click and drag to select Text in react-pdf-viewer
Click to review Error MessageImage
"Failed to execute 'setStart' on 'Range': There is no child at offset 26 "
I am encountering the above error when trying to select multiple lines of text or a paragraph. The problem occurs as follows:
When I double-click a line, it selects the line correctly.
However, when I click and drag to select multiple lines or a paragraph, the selection does not work as expected and causes issues.
is there any solution for this?
Thank you for your assistance!
const renderHighlightTarget = (props) => {
        return (
          <div
          style={{
              background: '#eee',
              display: 'flex',
              position: 'absolute',
              left: `${props.selectionRegion.left}%`,
              top: `${props.selectionRegion.top + props.selectionRegion.height}%`,
              transform: 'translate(0, 8px)',
          }}
      >
              <Button
                  // onClick={() => handleSelection(props.selectedText)}
                  style={{ zIndex: 11111 }}
              >
                  <MessageIcon />
              </Button>
          </div>
      );
  };
  const renderHighlights = (props) => {
  
      return (
          <div>
              {areas
                  .filter(area => area.pageIndex === props.pageIndex)
                  .map((area, idx) => (
                      <div
                          key={idx}
                          className="highlight-area"
                          style={{
                              background: 'yellow',
                              opacity: 0.4,
                              position: 'absolute',
                              borderRadius: '2px',
                              ...props.getCssProperties(area,props.rotation),
                          }}
                      />
                  ))}
          </div>
      );
  };

  const handleSelection = (selectedText) => {
      console.log('Handling Selection:', selectedText);
      
  
      // Handle selection logic here
  };

  const highlightPluginInstance = highlightPlugin({
      renderHighlights,
      renderHighlightTarget,
  });

let { switchTrigger } = highlightPluginInstance;
useEffect(() => {
  if (highlightPluginInstance) {
      switchTrigger(Trigger.TextSelection);
  }
}, [highlightPluginInstance, switchTrigger]);```

